# How can I repair a Minion Pro font installation that lacks certain features?

Tags: fonts, installing, classicthesis, package-options, minionpro

I was overzealous in my installation of Minion Pro and accidentally installed metrics that I do not have. Specifically (it seems), [I unzipped `metrics-opticals.zip`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/), when I shouldn't have.

As a result, certain packages (e.g. [`classicthesis`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/)) report an error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-BoldCapt.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

Is there a way to repair this (short of [purchasing the "opticals"](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1721) that my installation now expects to be there)?

---

I understand that when I use the `MinionPro` package directly, I can choose the `noopticals` option (the default), but I'm using `classicthesis`, and don't see a way to disable opticals there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wasn't able to test this because I don't have the `MinionPro` package installed, but the following code snippet may be of help:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{noopticals}{MinionPro}
\usepackage[minionpro]{classicthesis}
```

Comment: Nice! That's solves the problem.